# Add days Temporal.Duration to Temporal.Instant() using javascript Temporal library

Tags: javascript, temporal

I'm working with `Temporal` javascript library to manage dates in a Node project and I have problem when I try to add an amount of days to a `Instant` type object, as following:

```js
const now = Temporal.Now.instant()
const durationInDays = Temporal.Duration.from({days: 1})
const newDate = now.add(durationInDays)
```

The code compiles, but it launchs a runtime exception with the following message:

```
caused by: RangeError: Duration field days not supported by Temporal.Instant. Try Temporal.ZonedDateTime instead.
```

A quick solution that it works for me can be transform the days to hours:

```js
const durationInHours = Temporal.Duration.from({hours: 1 * 24})
const newDate = now.add(durationInHours)
```

or maybe do that the error says, using a `ZonedDateTime`, transforming the `Instant`:

```js
const newDate = now.toZonedDateTime('UTC').add(durationInDays).toInstant()
```

So my question is why I cannot add a `Duration` object with days to the `Instant` now

Comment: You should use hours because days are not always exactly 24 hours. Check out [this answer from one of the champions of `proposal-temporal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75562356/11019230). And [the code where the fields are excluded](https://github.com/js-temporal/temporal-polyfill/blob/bf2b199d3eed630674c8389f5fd4d0548566a467/lib/ecmascript.ts#L5570-L5593).

Comment: The length of a day depends on the date and the timezone, which an `Instant` does not have.

Comment: Thanks @zouabi. I'm wondering why I didn't find that question when I was looking for a solution.